# Screen size and density of Samsung Galaxy Y

Tags: screen, samsung-galaxy-y

I want to know about the screen size and density of the [Samsung Galaxy Y](http://www.samsung.com/in/consumer/mobile-phone/mobile-phone/smartphone/GT-S5360MAAINU). Which category of screen size (small, normal, large,x-large) or density (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, x-hdpi) is its screen? Any references would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the following diagram from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) you can see where it falls in the specs:

[image]

It's **3 inches** diagonally - it falls in the "small" category.

It's **133ppi** - which is definitely ldpi.

Comment: can you tell me by looking at the following link, in which category does it falls?
http://www.samsung.com/in/consumer/mobile-phone/mobile-phone/smartphone/GT-S5360MAAINU

Comment: That's exactly what I did, it says 3 inch, 320x240, which is 133ppi == ldpi on a small screen

Comment: Yeah, didn't noticed it earlier. Thanks for the help